# SharePoint Files.Add performance

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I want to add a file with SharePoint Server Object Model (--> my code runs on the server), my code does work but the calls of `Files.Add` and `SPListItem.Update()` are *very slow*.

For a 5 MB file the call to `Files.Add` takes about 11 seconds and the call to `SPListItem.Update` to set the metadata takes about 4 seconds.

```
 private void UploadSimple()
        {
            var metadata = GetSalesArticleInsertDemoData();
            string fileName = "sample2.jpg";
            FileStream file = File.OpenRead(fileName);  

            using(SPSite site = new SPSite(SPURL))
            {
                using(SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    SPList destinationList = GetListToBeUploadedIn(); // fast

                    SPFile fileDetails = destinationList.RootFolder.Files.Add("test000001.jpg", file, null, false); // slow

                    SPListItem newItem = fileDetails.ListItemAllFields;
                    FillListItemWithData(metadata, newItem); // fast, a few fields get filled with sample data

                    newItem.Update(); // slow                    
                }
            }
        }
```

Uploading the same file and setting metadata via the Client Object Model is finished in about 9 seconds and here the file has to be transferred over the network.

Does anybody know or have a clue what can be the  cause of the slowness?